# Ionic livereload error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, livereload

I am getting this error in my console.

```
No response for http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 found in cache. About to fetch from network...
```

When I make a change to my app, the app reloads and builds but I do not see the changes in the browser.

Also, when I try `ionic serve` on another app, it reloads my current app.

When I go to `http://localhost:8100/` my app is there even if I don't use `ionic serve`.

I have done `npm cache clean`
removed ionic from computer and re-added.

But still get that error.

Ionic info:

```
cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v4.6.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled cordova, ionic and npm. Then reinstalled all.

The livereload error was not there anymore, but I still couldn't see any changes to my app when I update it.
But after trying my app in incognito (without extensions), it then seems to show and everything was fine.

Seems to be Adblocker or some extension that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me now and I solved it by opening the page with my local ip address instead of localhost.

If you are running on Windows you can open the CMD and type `ipconfig`. This will retrieve your local ip address. Your ip address should be at `Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet -> IPv4 Address` .

For example, if your ip is 10.1.1.15 you should open http://10.1.1.15:8100/ in your browser so that you can use live reload.